# Unable to use a Stored Procedure with my Entity Framework v4 + POCO's :(

Tags: .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, poco

I've got a very simple **Entity Framework** project with **POCO Entities**. I've got a single `stored procedure` which I have imported using the `EF Wizard`. Kewl.

I've then made my own `EF Entity` which I've then `Add Function Import` to map the `Stored Procedure` to my `EF Entity`.

Now ... I'm not sure how to map my `EF Entity` to a `POCO`. As such, I keep getting the following error:

> Error 11007: Entity type 'XXXXX' is
>   not mapped.

I'm not sure how I can map this entity to a `POCO`. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

S'Ok. this is what I ended up doing.

#### Using POCO's

Ie. the `.edmx`, `Custom Tool` is removed / no auto-generated entities, etc.

1. Import Function :: manually import the stored procedure.

In your context class ...

```
public class SqlServerContext : ObjectContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public SqlServerContext(EntityConnection entityConnection, 
                            ILoggingService loggingService)
        : base(entityConnection) { .... }

    public ObjectResult<Location> FindLocationsWithinABoundingBox(decimal upperLeftLongitude,
                                                                  decimal upperLeftLatitude,
                                                                  decimal lowerRightLongitude,
                                                                  decimal lowerRightLatitude)
    {
        return base.ExecuteFunction<Location>("FindLocationsWithinABoundingBox",
                                              new ObjectParameter("UpperLeftLatitude", upperLeftLongitude),
                                              new ObjectParameter("UpperLeftLongitude", upperLeftLatitude),
                                              new ObjectParameter("LowerRightLongitude", lowerRightLongitude),
                                              new ObjectParameter("LowerRightLatitude", lowerRightLatitude));
    }
}
```

#### Using the Auto-Generated Entities, etc. (The default way EF is setup)

1. Create a custom COMPLEX TYPE (which will be used to map the stored procedure, too).
2. Import Function :: manually import the stored procedure.
3. Map the RETURN TYPE (of the imported sp) to the custom COMPLEX TYPE you've made.

dat's it.

Not sure if my POCO way is the best way to do things, but it .. well .. works :)

And [this is a related StackOverflow question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385648/possible-to-use-the-repository-pattern-stored-procedures-should-can-they-re) about using this stored procedure in a services / IQueryable way ... :)

Comment: I am facing the same problem. How did you map the return type to the custom complex type? Can you may be provide an example? Thanks in advance

Comment: A bit old for a comment, but did you realise you've got: "UpperLeftLatitude" => upperLeftLongitude and vice versa in the code above? i.e. latitude maps to longitude?

Comment: HAHAHA :) nice find :) nope :( i didn't